# Any tools can make a vim dict file easier?

Tags: vim

Any tools can make a vim dict file easier?

I can get all the keywords but I need to sort them, remove duplicated words

Comment: you mean like `sort -u` or `sort|uniq`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you can work with the UNIX tools

Note also that vim has :sort built-in

```
:sort
:'<,'>sort    # selection
:*sort        # idem, if cpo-=* (see :help cpo-star)
```

So you could make a visual selection and do

```
:*!sort|uniq -dc
```

to view duplicates with duplication count

```
:*!sort -u
```

to remove duplicates and sort the selection

Use `:%` to act on the full file

Comment: thanks, I'd like to ask another question, I want to keep the line only match /^##.*$, and drop the rest, cause the api doc is written in markdown, can I do this?

Comment: thanks, can you take a look my another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112727/vim-map-c-xc-k-without-auto-insert-first-match

Comment: Vim's built-in sort can also remove duplicates: `:*sort u`